# How to make js work with specific html blocks?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following js code

```
$(function () {
 "use strict";

var maxText = $("textarea").attr("maxlength"),
    
    ourMessage = $(".message");

ourMessage.html('<span>' + maxText + '</span> Characters Remaining');

$("textarea").keydown(function () {
   
    var textLength = $(this).val().length,
        
        remText = maxText - textLength;
    
    ourMessage.html('<span>' + remText + '</span> Characters Remaining');
    
});


 $("textarea").keyup(function () {
   
    var textLength = $(this).val().length,
        
        remText = maxText - textLength;
    
    ourMessage.html('<span>' + remText + '</span> Characters Remaining');
    
}); });
```

and the following html code snippet:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea id="field" placeholder="Type Here" maxlength="3000" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
        <div class="message"></div>
    </div>
```

and it works fine.
But I need more than one of  html snippets on the same page and I don't know how to change the code so  `<div class="message"></div>` only changes when "it's" `textarea` is used.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the div is always directly after the textarea, you can simply call the `next` method on the textarea to get the div.